# Find Max column value of np array with slice

Tags: python, numpy

```py
import numpy as np

m_array = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 45.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                    [2.0, 3.0,  0.0, 0.0, 2.0],
                    [1.0, 4.0,  0.0, 1.0, 3.0]])
m_array 
[[ 1.  2. 45.  0.  1.]
 [ 2.  3.  0.  0.  2.]
 [ 1.  4.  0.  1.  3.]]
```

How can I slice my numpy array get max value in column 2 i.e. 45 if my condition is column 0 value must be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to filter the array first

```
np.max(m_array[m_array[:, 0] == 1, 1])
```